# IPv6 NDP timer problem

Tags: kernel, ip, kernel-modules, ipv6, ipv4

Need to change Fedora Linux's IPv6 stack for NDP DAD timer changes.

How to locate the Fedora's IPv6 and IPv4 stack in Fedora distribution dvd/site so that, we can recompile and generate new stack ?

Answer (score 2):

To change the NDP DAD timing, use `sysctl`.  The sysctl-key to look at is `net.ipv6.neigh.<if>.retrans_time_ms`.

Answer (score 0):

"Fedora" doesn't have an IPv4/IPv6 stack.  "Fedora" is a distribution -- a collection of tools and utilities.  Fedora is built around "Linux", which *does* have a network stack.  You can find the source code to Linux at [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/), where you can download everything as a tarball, or clone the [git](http://git-scm.org) repository at [git.kernel.org](https://git.kernel.org/).  [The Kernel Hacker's Guide to Git](https://git.kernel.org/) has some useful information on getting started if you opt for this method.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, does it?